# équivalent coloré et moderne de "poule mouillée / mauviette / femmelettes "

Tags: expressions, synonymes

Les équivalents proposés m’ont l’air un plutôt vieillot ― "poule mouillée, mauviette"― vulgaire et/ou discriminatoire ―"on n’est pas des femmelettes / pédés tarlouzes" (et les autres du genre focalisant sur le "manque de virilité").

Connaissez-vous d’autres équivalents modernes ?

Je recherche un terme non vulgaire et non discriminatoire, mais je suis aussi curieux d’entendre les non-conformes (vous pouvez vous lâcher).

Answer (score 3):

Dans les termes courants en ce moments, je peux citer :

"*Fragile*" qui est assez populaire, mais difficile de dire si c'est vraiment non discriminatoire. Ça se rapproche de tous les équivalents homophobes mais sans y faire allusion directement. On le rencontre parfois comme adjectif mais il s'utilise surtout comme nom.

On a aussi "*victime*", pour quelqu'un qui se laisse marcher dessus, qui ne s'impose pas. Ça s'éloigne peut-être du sens que tu cherches.

Il reste toujours un paquet de termes discriminatoires, mais je pense qu'ils sont un peu moins utilisés qu'avant.

Comment: *Fragile* ne fait pas référence aux homo, contrairement à *tapette* et autres qui étaient d'abord des termes désignant les homo avant de devenir des termes désignant un manque de virilité (sur le même modèle que des termes féminins comme *femmelette*). Et pour ma part, je dirais que même les termes homophobes ont perdu un peu de cette référence à l'homosexualité, pour ne désigner que la "fragilité" — on pourrait donc être homo mais être "un bonhomme", ou être hétéro mais être "une tarlouze". Mais gros +1 pour *fragile* qui est à la fois moderne et sans connotation homophobe ou sexiste.

Comment: Ne passez vous pas un peu à côté? J'aurais gardé le sens de _peu courageux_, _peureux_ sans me concentrer autant sur l'aspect homosexuel, que je n'entends pas forcément dans _poule mouillée_?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps je partage ton interprétation. Par contre je n'ai jamais entendu "Fragile" dans ce contexte. Ca se dit ça: "on n'est pas des fragiles !" ? (Ca sonne bien en tout cas !)

Comment: @Guillaume Oui c'est très utilisé, c'est relativement récent (deux ou trois ans). C'est beaucoup utilisé sur les réseaux sociaux.

Comment: @Guillaume Si tu veux une petite mise en contexte, tu peux aller regarder par [ici](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K23ZXGZr4s4)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat +1 pour l'exemple, merci beaucoup!